# How to form a set of all ordinals up to e.g. $\omega_0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

My question is pretty basic. In Set-Theory we're used to the construction of new sets from the existing ones using the Axiom of Specification. But what if I'd like to construct a set of all ordinals less than some fixed ordinal?

E.g. Let's take e.g. $W(\omega_0) = \{ \beta \ | \ \beta < \omega_0\}$. Axiom of Specification requires one to construct a set out of an already **existing set**. Since we know that the collection of all ordinals is [not a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox), then how can one even build the above $W(\omega_0)$?

In other words, I have the $W(\omega_0) = \{ \beta \in \textbf{?} \ | \ \beta < \omega_0\}$ problem.

Comment: The set $W(\omega_0)$ as you want it **is** the set $\omega_0$: an ordinal is **the same** as the set of its predecessors, like $0=\emptyset$, $1 = \{0\}=\{\emptyset\}$ etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I guess I lack some basic ordinal theory knowledge. So it turns out that the Axiom of Specification isn't used at all but rather $W(\omega_0) = \omega_0$. Thank you. If you form your comment into an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $W(\omega_0)$ that you want to define **is** the set $\omega_0$.

An ordinal is just ( as a set) the set of all its predecessors, cf.

$0=\emptyset$, $1 = \{0\} = \{\emptyset\}$, $2=\{0,1\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, $\omega= \{0,1,2,3,\ldots,\}$ etc.

See the definition by von Neumann on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals), e.g. The axiom of foundation in ZF allows us to define ordinals as transitive sets that are linearly ordered by $\in$. It's quite elegant IMO.